# Base64 decode in SAP ASE using XML Services

Tags: sap-ase

I wish to Base64-decode data in SAP ASE using SQL. I can do the inverse (Base64-encode binary data) using the following approach:

```
-- PREPARATION: get HEX bytes of ASCII string as test input for Base64-encode
select bintostr(convert(varbinary(16384), 'test'))
-- returns 74657374

-- WORKS: Base64 from HEX
select xmlextract('//C1/text()', c_xml) from (select (select cast(strtobin('74657374') as varbinary(16384)) for xml option 'binary=base64')) t(c_xml)
-- returns dGVzdA==
```

However, the following approach of using the XMLTABLE function with an explicit data conversion back to VARBINARY doesn't decode the Base64-encoded data, but instead returns the hex-bytes of the Base64 characters:

```
-- FAILS: HEX from Base64
select c_bin from xmltable('/rows/row' passing '<rows><row><col>dGVzdA==</col></row></rows>' columns col varbinary(16384)) t(c_bin)
-- returns 0x6447567a64413d3d instead of 0x74657374
```

Is there any fix to the last query or alternative approach to get back the original binary value 0x74657374?

Answer (score 0):

Credits to the friendly folks at SAP ASE community for the following solution, originally posted [here](https://answers.sap.com/questions/13683772/base64-decode-in-sap-ase-using-xml-services.html).

As of its current release 16 SP04, SAP ASE's built-in SQL/XML facilities support only *encoding to*, but not *decoding from* Base64, unfortunately. Hence, developers need to implement their own Base64 decoder, for example as a user-defined function in Sybase's Transact SQL dialect.

The following UDF accepts a VARCHAR input buffer of maxiumm 16384 Base64 characters. Larger size inputs, such as Base64-encoded CLOBs, would thus require chunking and looping.

```sql
create or replace function base64_decode(@enc_char varchar(16384))
returns varbinary(16384) as
begin
    declare @alphabet varbinary(65)
        set @alphabet = convert(varbinary(65), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=')
    declare @i int 
        set @i = 0
    declare @enc1 int
    declare @enc2 int
    declare @enc3 int
    declare @enc4 int
    declare @chr1 int
    declare @chr2 int
    declare @chr3 int
    declare @dec varbinary(16384)
    declare @enc varbinary(16384)
    set @enc = convert(varbinary(16384), @enc_char)

    while @i < len(@enc)
    begin
        set @enc1 = locate( @alphabet, substring(@enc, @i + 1, 1)) - 1
        set @enc2 = locate( @alphabet, substring(@enc, @i + 2, 1)) - 1
        set @enc3 = locate( @alphabet, substring(@enc, @i + 3, 1)) - 1
        set @enc4 = locate( @alphabet, substring(@enc, @i + 4, 1)) - 1

        set @chr1 = ( (@enc1 * 4) & 0xFF )  | (@enc2 / 16)
        set @chr2 = ( (@enc2 & 0x0F) * 16 ) | (@enc3 / 4 )
        set @chr3 = ( (@enc3 & 0x03) * 64 ) |  @enc4

        set @dec = @dec || cast(@chr1  as varbinary(1)) 

        if ( @enc3 != 64 and @enc3 is not null ) 
          set @dec = @dec || cast(@chr2  as varbinary(1)) 

        if ( @enc4 != 64 and @enc4 is not null ) 
          set @dec = @dec || cast(@chr3  as varbinary(1)) 

        set @i = @i + 4
    end

    return  @dec

end
```